# Disabling automatic add after resolving git conflict

Tags: git, vc-mode

After updating emacs (to 25.2.2 as shipping in ubuntu 18.04) I notice a change that completely breaks my conflict resolution flow in git. Once I resolve a conflict using emacs and save the file, emacs automatically does "git add" on the file. This may seem convenient but it removes the chance to see the resulting "3-way conflict diff" (I have no idea what this is really called in git speak).

Is there a way to disable this auto-add of the resolved file? I have tried disabling smerge-mode in the buffer before saving but that does not seem to help. I can't even figure out which mode is doing the actual auto-add either.

On further investigation the problematic behaviour seems to be caused by the vc-git-resolve-when-done hook. So the question seems to be how to disable this after-save-hook.

Comment: You should make your comment an answer and then accept it. That marks the question as "answered" and helps future visitors when they search.

Comment: Now that you have made it into an answer, please accept it (assuming of course that it does what you want :-) ): just tick the tick mark on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the `vc-git-resolve-conflicts` variable. Setting this to `nil` removes automatic git-add after conflict resolution.